# Is it possible to use variables in SASS' @import rules?

Tags: string, variables, import, sass, concatenation

As the title says, is it possible to use variables in SASS' `@import` rules?

As an example, if I need to import the following files

```
@import "./path/to/my/desired/file-1";
@import "./path/to/my/desired/file-2";
@import "./path/to/my/desired/file-3";
```

can I do something like this?

```
$dir: "./path/to/my/desired/";

@import $dir + "file-1";
@import $dir + "file-1";
@import $dir + "file-1";
```

Given that the previous was just an example of what I want to achieve, and that this syntax of course isn't working, is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the Sass documentation:](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import)

> **It's not possible to dynamically import a Sass file based on a variable**; interpolation is only for CSS imports. As such, it only works with url() imports.

So, yes.
You can import files using a Sass variable, but it just can't be a Sass file.

**Example:**

```scss
$foo: 'bar';
@import url('#{$foo}.css'); // will import `bar.css`
```